# I can' t connect to internet anymore after i tried to deploy algo

Tags: networking, server, vpn, openssh

When deploying algo i get an error because the server stops to have the internet connection (but the client, same connection, doesn' t have any problem).
In the virtual machine (server) rebooting solves the problem (but i can' t finish to deploy algo).
In the physical (another server) pc i checked the `/etc/network/interfaces` file, added the route gateway (ip of the router) becasue it seemed that i can' t connect to it, and reboot many times but i can' t use the internet connection anymore.
 The pc doens' t show any error but i can' t connect to anything, but to the other pc using the LAN.
But i can' t use openssh anymore.

Comment: what does ifconfig look like before/after deploying algo?

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte after/before is the same (virtual machine), physical pc i can' t (no internet anymore). Do you need to see it? Is totally normal like this https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uifconfi.htm

Comment: I wonder if algo changes your dns or default router? there is a script somewhere that will collect all your network info, lemme see if I can find it

Comment: here is that script for collecting network info: https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814 run it while your network is working, then run algo to break your network, then run the script again and post both outputs.

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte done. Can be that deploying algo locally it changes the iptables rules? If yes how i can check/fix them?

Comment: I honestly don't know. I am just doing my best to help you troubleshoot your problem. Do you run algo as root?

Comment: no i run it as myuser and without using sudo (myuser@mypc:~$ ./algo)

Answer (score 1):

Double check your installation steps to ensure nothing was missed:

The easiest way to get an Algo server running is to let it set up a new virtual machine in the cloud for you.

1. Setup an account on a cloud hosting provider. Algo supports DigitalOcean (most user friendly), Amazon Lightsail, Amazon EC2, Microsoft Azure, Google Compute Engine, Scaleway and OpenStack.
2. Download Algo. Unzip it in a convenient location on your local machine.
3. Install Algo's core dependencies. Open the Terminal. The python interpreter you use to deploy Algo must be python2. If you don't know what this means, you're probably fine. cd into the algo-master directory where you unzipped Algo, then run:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install \
       build-essential \
       libssl-dev \
       libffi-dev \
       python-dev \
       python-pip \
       python-setuptools \
       python-virtualenv -y
   ```
4. Install Algo's remaining dependencies. Use the same Terminal window as the previous step and run:

   ```
   $ python -m virtualenv --python=$(which python2) env &&
       source env/bin/activate &&
       python -m pip install -U pip &&
       python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
   ```
5. List the users to create. Open config.cfg in your favorite text editor. Specify the users you wish to create in the users list.
6. Start the deployment. Return to your terminal. In the Algo directory, run ./algo and follow the instructions. There are several optional features available. None are required for a fully functional VPN server. These optional features are described in greater detail in `deploy-from-ansible.md`.

That's it! You will get the message below when the server deployment process completes. You now have an Algo server on the internet. Take note of the p12 (user certificate) password in case you need it later, it will only be displayed this time.

Source: https://github.com/trailofbits/algo/blob/master/README.md

**NOTE**: I changed ` which python2 ` to `$(which python2)` because a <kbd>`</kbd> key might be confused with a <kbd>'</kbd> key.